# Probability that $n$ trials will succeed given that $k$ succeeded

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, accuracy

I'm not sure exactly how to ask this, or if there is such a thing.  I'm new to statistics and have just studied confidence intervals and confidence levels of survey data, such as the confidence of population mean being within the certain interval around the sample mean.

I'd like to measure some confidence in data accuracy.

I'm doing some data munging at work, basically copying some data from a source, manipulating it a bit, and then storing it in a database. I'd like to be able to tell my manager that I'm confident that the data is accurate to a certain level.

I plan on verifying the data with another tool, sampling the calculated data vs. original data (say randomly picking 10000 entries of the 62000000 and recalculating to verify), and assuming the entire sample matches, report that I am x% confident that the entire set of calculated data is correct.

However, I'm not sure what I'm measuring.  I don't want to measure a mean, but instead the accuracy of n% of the population, and infer if that means that m% is indeed accurate.

Can I only be confident that if I verify n% of the population is accurate, that only n% is accurate?

Comment: Related: [How to tell the probability of failure if there were no failures?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/134380/7290)

Comment: @DeltaIV It's almost a duplicate, but not quite: the referenced thread concerns the special case of one future sample, rather than an arbitrary number of future samples (if I understand the present question correctly, and I'm not sure I do).

Comment: @whuber I disagree. The OP observes $n$ (10000) successes out of $n$ trials, i.e., a realization of $X \sim Binom(n,p)$ and s/he wants to be "x% confident that the entire set of calculated data is correct". With $n$ successes out of $n$ trials, the point estimate for the successive value of the Binomial variable $Y\sim Binom(m,p)$, i.e.,  for the number of successes out of $m$ (61,990,000) successive trials is $m\hat{p}=m\frac{n}{n}=m$ successes, i.e., all successes. Thus a prediction interval for $Y$ given an observation of $X$ is precisely what's the OP is looking for.

Comment: @DeltaIV I also provided an answer to a similar problem (from the perspective of sample size calculation) using median unbiased estimation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315984/sample-size-calculation-for-estimating-0-probability-in-finite-sample-binary-dat/318241#318241) I suspect your approach and mine are essentially similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think of this is as repeated Bernoulli trials with an equal probability of success $θ$. Suppose you observe 10,000 trials, all of which succeed, and you want to know the probability that an additional 62,000,000 - 10,000 = 61,990,000 trials would also all succeed. I'm at a loss to formulate a frequentist approach to this problem, using a confidence interval. But a Bayesian approach seems natural: you want the posterior probability of all 61,990,000 trials succeeding given your prior beliefs about $θ$ and the 10,000 observed successes.

Let $θ$ have a $\operatorname{Beta}(α, β)$ prior. Then its posterior distribution is $\operatorname{Beta}(10,000 + α, β)$. Then the posterior predictive probability for success of a single future trial [happens to be](https://web.archive.org/web/20170228000517/https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10701/lecture/technote2_betabinomial.pdf) just the posterior mean of $θ$, which is

$$\frac{10,000 + α}{10,000 + α + β} \quad .$$

For the probability that 61,990,000 independent trials succeed, just raise this quotient to the 61,990,000th power.

It is interesting to note that because 61,990,000 is so large, this probability will be very small unless $α$ is *much* larger than $β$; that is, unless you were already virtually certain that your method was extremely accurate before you even observed those 10,000 successes.

Comment: Thanks!  I was wondering if some Bayesian approach would be the answer.  And making the sample larger shouldn't really be a problem.  10,000 was a simple number.  I could easily run the sample to 1,000,000 if necessary.

Comment: "For the probability that 61,990,000 independent trials succeed, just raise this quotient to the 61,990,000th power.". Are you sure? I think the future trials are not independent, they are only independent given $\theta$... or am I missing something?

Comment: @BenoitSanchez Yes, they're independent conditional on $θ$, or in terms more familiar to Bayesians, exchangeable. You could recompute the probability with each successive future observation, but the asker seemed interested in the probability of them all succeeding without checking past the first $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I will build on the answer by @Kodiologist but show that frequentist answers are possibe.  What we need is the concept of *predictive likelihood*,  see https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1177012175.  The idea is to build a likelihood function for an unobserved random variable.  There are multiple ways of doing this.

Let $X=(X_1, \dotsc, X_n)$ be the observed variables (in the exmple $n=10000$) and $Y=(Y_1, \dotsc, Y_m)$ be the future (unobserved) variables, so we want a predictive likelihood for $\sum_j Y_y$. $X,Y$ have independent bernoulli distributions with the same parameter $\theta$.  We write $x=\sum_i X_i, y= \sum_j Y_j$, and the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ based on $x, y$ is $\hat{\theta}_y = \frac{x+y}{n+m}$.

Then the *profile predictive likelihood* for $y$ is 
$$
   L_p(y | x) = \sup_\theta f_\theta (y,x) = L_y(y,\hat{\theta}_y)
$$
where $L_y$ is the usual likelihood function based on $x,y$.  For our example model this becomes 
$$
   L_p(y | x) = \sup_\theta \binom{n}{x} \theta^x (1-\theta)^{n-x} \binom{m}{y} \theta^y (1-\theta)^{m-y}
$$
and when we have observed $x=n$ this reduces to 
$$
   L_p(y | x) = \binom{m}{y} \left( \frac{n+y}{n+m} \right)^{n+y} \left( \frac{m-y}{n+m}\right)^{m-y}  
$$
(I will come back and extend this answer)

Comment: I think you may find this answer of mine interesting https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/256706/58675